# Eclipse Galieo - No completions available

Tags: php, eclipse, galileo

Eclipse Platform 3.5.1.M20090917-0800 org.eclipse.platform.ide
EPP PHP Feature 1.2.1.20090918-0703 org.eclipse.epp.package.php.feature.feature.group

When I write

```
$_var = new MyClass();
```

and press Ctrl+Enter, i see class methods, but when i write

```
public $math;
...
$this->math = new BaseMath();
```

and press Ctrl+Enter, i see "**no completions available**". Why?

Answer (score 0):

Php Feature 1.2.1?
That seems old, considering most of the completion issues reported [by this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.pdt/msg03800.html) have been fixed in PDT 2.1

- [bug 275540](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=275540)
- [bug 274322](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=274322)

Although, that one is still opened.

- [bug 268312](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=268312) (namespace aliases, not your case)

And that one has been reopened:

- [bug 281766](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=281766) (when passing by global namespace '`/`')

So did you try with the latest PDT version?